# ¿Cómo comparo los valores de un Query set de una tabla especifica y una columna especifica en Django 3.1?

Tags: python, django, sql

espero que puedan ayudarme con este proyecto en Django, estoy realizando un juego de preguntas que compara la respuesta correcta con la que selecciono el usuario en un select son 10 preguntas en total por cada desafío, cada respuesta correcta tiene 1 punto y si es incorrecta no le suma nada, todo guardado en una base de datos, cuando todas las respuestas están correctas el programa arroja 10 como resultado que es correcto pero cuando se equivocan en alguna arroja mal los resultados como 0 o 5, 6 lo hace mal y la lógica en el código la veo bien pero no se por que me arroja mal cuando se equivocan. Me imagino que el problema esta cuando comparo la respuesta que esta en la base de datos con la que selecciono el usuario pero arroja mal el resultado del puntaje cuando se equivocan el alguna. No se si hay algo mal en el diccionario del query set o en la comparación con el if dentro del for. Espero que puedan ayudarme. Las respuestas que selecciono el usuario las guardo en una lista y las comparo con las que estan en la base de datos.

**views.py**

@login_required
def resultados(request, subtema_id, jugador_id, tema_id):

```
if request.method == "POST":

    respuesta0 = request.POST.get("respuesta1")
    
    respuesta1 = request.POST.get("respuesta2")

    respuesta2 = request.POST.get("respuesta3")

    respuesta3 = request.POST.get("respuesta4")
    
    respuesta4 = request.POST.get("respuesta5")

    respuesta5 = request.POST.get("respuesta6")

    respuesta6 = request.POST.get("respuesta7")

    respuesta7 = request.POST.get("respuesta8")

    respuesta8 = request.POST.get("respuesta9")

    respuesta9 = request.POST.get("respuesta10")
    
    subtema = Subtema.objects.get(id=subtema_id)
```

// puede que tambien este el error en este query set.
respuestas_correctas = Pregunta.objects.filter(subtema=subtema).values('respuesta_correcta')

```
    puntos = 0

    respuestas_jugador = [respuesta0,respuesta1,respuesta2,respuesta3,respuesta4,respuesta5,respuesta6,respuesta7,respuesta8,respuesta9]

    i = 0

    for value in respuestas_correctas:
 
   // creo que el error esta aqui en esta comparacion
        if value["respuesta_correcta"] == respuestas_jugador[i]:

            puntos = puntos + 1

            i = i + 1

    punto = Punto(jugador_id=jugador_id, tema_id=tema_id, subtema_id=subtema_id, puntuacion=puntos)

    punto.save()

    return render(request, "resultados.html", {"punto": puntos})

else:

    response = redirect('/inicio/')

    return response
```

**El formulario que uso**

```html
  {% for subtema in nombre_subtema %}
                  <form method="post" name="desafio" id="desafio" action="/resultados/{{subtema.id}}/{% for jugador_id in id_jugador %}{{jugador_id.id}}{% endfor %}/{% for tema in nombre_tema %}{{tema.id}}{% endfor %}/" onsubmit="enableSample();">{% endfor %}{% csrf_token %}
                  {% for pregunta in preguntas %}
                  <li>
                     <h4>{{pregunta.texto}}</h4>
                   <select class="form-control" name="respuesta{{forloop.counter}}" id="respuesta{{forloop.counter}}" required>
                     <option value="">Selecciona respuesta...</option>
                     <option value="{{pregunta.respuesta1}}">{{pregunta.respuesta1}}</option>
                     <option value="{{pregunta.respuesta2}}">{{pregunta.respuesta2}}</option>
                     <option value="{{pregunta.respuesta3}}">{{pregunta.respuesta3}}</option>
                   </select>
                  </li><br>
                  {% endfor %}
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-body -->
              <div class="card-footer clearfix" align="center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="bPreguntar = false;">Enviar Desafio</button>
              </form>
```

**Mis modelos models.py**

```
from django.db import models
```

## Create your models here.

class Tema(models.Model):

```
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'temas',null=True,blank=True)
subtitulo = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
icono = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'tema'
    verbose_name_plural = 'temas'

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' %(self.nombre)
```

class Subtema(models.Model):

```
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150)
icono = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'subtema',default=None)
subtitulo = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=None)
musica = models.FileField(upload_to = 'music', null=True, blank=True,default=None)
tiempo = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
tema = models.ForeignKey(Tema, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'subtema'
    verbose_name_plural = 'subtemas'

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre
```

class Pregunta(models.Model):

```
texto = models.CharField(max_length=500)
imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='preguntas',null=True,blank=True)
respuesta1 = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=None)
respuesta2 = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=None)
respuesta3 = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=None)
respuesta_correcta = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=None)
subtema = models.ForeignKey(Subtema, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'pregunta'
    verbose_name_plural = 'preguntas'

def __str__(self):
    return self.texto,self.respuesta_correcta
```

class Jugador(models.Model):

```
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
apellido = models.CharField(max_length=100)
correo = models.CharField(max_length=120,unique=True)
nickname = models.CharField(max_length=150,default=None)
password = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'jugador'
    verbose_name_plural = 'jugadores'

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s %s' %(self.nombre,self.correo,self.nickname)
```

class Punto(models.Model):

```
jugador = models.ForeignKey(Jugador, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
tema = models.ForeignKey(Tema, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
subtema = models.ForeignKey(Subtema, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
puntuacion = models.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'punto'
    verbose_name_plural = 'puntos'

def __str__(self):
    return self.puntuacion
```

class Subtema_jugador(models.Model):

```
subtema = models.ForeignKey(Subtema, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
jugador = models.ForeignKey(Jugador, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
presente = models.BooleanField()

class Meta: 
    verbose_name = 'Subtema_jugador'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Subtema_jugadores'

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.presente)
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias pero ya consegui la solucion, solo tenia que meter los valores de las respuestas del jugador en un diccionario y listo! :)

```
respuestas_correctas = Pregunta.objects.filter(subtema=subtema).values('respuesta_correcta')

    puntos = 0

    respuestas_jugador = [{'respuesta_correcta': respuesta0},
    {'respuesta_correcta': respuesta1}, 
    {'respuesta_correcta':respuesta2},{'respuesta_correcta':respuesta3},
    {'respuesta_correcta':respuesta4},{'respuesta_correcta':respuesta5},
    {'respuesta_correcta':respuesta6},{'respuesta_correcta':respuesta7},
    {'respuesta_correcta':respuesta8},{'respuesta_correcta':respuesta9}]

    for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:

        if respuestas_correctas[i] == respuestas_jugador[i]:

           puntos = puntos + 1
```